# Laravel Unexpected Data found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to calculate time difference in minutes via Laravel and Carbon.

My query: `$findPauseWorky = ClockingSystemHours::where('total_time','=', null)->where('worky_id','=',$id)->whereNotNull('end_time')->get();`

When I get my collection from my query the result looks like this:

```
Collection {#407
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => ClockingSystemHours {#408
      #dates: array:3 [
        0 => "start_time"
        1 => "end_time"
        2 => "total_time"
      ]
      #original: array:8 [
        "id" => 2
        "start_time" => "16:21:29"
        "end_time" => "23:20:52"
        "total_time" => null
        "worky_id" => 2
        "employee_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2019-01-24 16:21:29"
        "updated_at" => "2019-01-24 16:21:29"
      ]
```

As you can see in the result I've set my `$dates` in my model.

If i execute this `dd($findPauseWorky->first()->start_time);` it results in this:

```
Unexpected data found.
    ↵Unexpected data found.
    ↵Data missing
```

When i execute this: `dd($findPauseWorky->first()->worky_id);` it results in this : 
`2`

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a reason why I cant access the data?

Comment: What is the Carbon function you're using?

Comment: It appears the `$findPauseWorky->dates->start_time` is empty, according to the array output.

Comment: Whoops that was a mistake, i was trying to access it via that, the error comes when i try this: `dd($findPauseWorky->first()->start_time);`

Comment: Edit your question, show us your code.

Comment: You have `start_time` and `end_time`  in `protected $dates` in your model, but neither are actual dates - they're times. So Carbon isn't able to parse them

Comment: Can you share the code for the `ClockingSystemHours` model?